# How to set compile command for a target in CMake from scratch?

Tags: cmake

In CMake, there is a tendency for many library-finding commands and CMake defaults to fill up your build commands with garbage that is totally irrelevant to a given target.

How can you blow away all of the flags/properties/settings that determine the compile options for a target so you can set just the ones you want?

I'm using cmake 2.8 since that's what's in Ubuntu 14.04, but hopefully there is some version that works across several cmake versions, despite the infuriatingly frequent renames of cmake variables and functions to subtly different names and subtly different behaviors.

At the moment I'm building a shared library from a single .c file, but I think my question applies in general for C and C++ libraries and executables.

Comment: What do you mean by "taget"? Is this CMake target, created by `add_executable`, `add_library` or `add_custom_target`? Or is this (other) machine, which should run compiled programs? (So, you perform *cross-compiling* and want to write universal toolchain file).

Comment: I updated my description. In my case I happened to be attempting to cross-compile in a single CMakeLists.txt, which apparently isn't supported in CMake at all. However, this is a frequent source of frustration for me even when not compiling. My CMake builds lack hygiene.

Comment: I don't quite undestand what you want. Do you want to make configuration  process *faster*? Or your problem is that CMake *incorrectly* determines some cross-compiler properties, so the project is failed to compile? `In my case I happened to be attempting to cross-compile in a single CMakeLists.txt` - Is it mean that you want to cross-compile *without separate toolchain file*? Example of the code would help a lot.

Comment: Have you ever looked at what CMake is actually passing to your compiler by switching on the CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE setting? There are people who have not (yet) had to care exactly what flags are being passed to their compiler, or even which compiler they're using...

Comment: And how this correlates with the question? Please, be specific. Currently your question post has single question: `How can you blow away all of the flags/properties/settings that determine the compile options... ?`, which is unclear for me (and seems, not only for me). I ask clarification, but instead you involve more and more CMake aspects: cross-compiling, CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.